# How to resolve SQL Server error "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'GROUP'"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

This is my query

```
INSERT INTO Tbl_DomainWiseStats (subdomainid, tendercount, Type_cat, DisplayText)
    SELECT 
        ' + CAST(@domain_id AS VARCHAR(100)) + '
        , TenderCount
        , ''ByCountry''
        ,Country 
    FROM 
        (SELECT DISTINCT 
             V.Country, 
             COUNT(DISTINCT Sr_No) as TenderCount 
         FROM 
             dbo.viewgetlivetenders V 
         WHERE 
             '+  @Domainquery +' 
         GROUP BY 
             V.Country) a 
ORDER BY  
    TenderCount
```

Error message:

> [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 4145)  An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'GROUP'

Comment: Provide a value for @Domainquery in your query

Comment: Can we see what this string expression resolves to in your question i.e. with all of the concatenated values injected? You should be able to echo this out to the console.

Comment: Please do not "tag spam". If you are using all versions of SQL Server, including 2008, 2012 and 2014 then maybe it is worth saying so explicitly in your question (this would be unusual). If you are just using one version then please just use the one you are actually using.

Comment: Since values for the missing data have not been provided, and the major version of the database server has not been fixed, I am voting this as unclear for the time being. The question is two days old now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to complete your `where` clause..

**This causes error:**

```
select * from test where id
```

**but not this:**

```
select * from test where id =1
```

In your dynamic SQL,below part is causing issue..

```
WHERE '+  @Domainquery +' 
                        GROUP BY V.Country
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't compare your where clause to anything.

`"WHERE '+  @Domainquery +' "` is incomplete, equal it to the value you want to compare.